# Drupal 6 readonly field

Tags: entities

I have created a cck field and made it's attribute to '**readonly**' through form alter. I also want to make sure that the **user won't change** it's value by **editing** through **firebug** or by any other means, for that I referred this [Making CCK fields read-only in Drupal 6](https://www.silviogutierrez.com/blog/making-cck-fields-read-only-drupal-6/).

But it is working fine for **text field** not for **integer field**. For integer field the default value in $form always change to what the user has submitted. Why it is not working for integer field and is there any other way I can accomplish this.

```
function my_survey_after_build($form, &$form_state) {                           
    $field = 'field_survey_name';                                         
    $field2 = 'field_survey_ques_1_weight';  

    $form[$field][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';                
    $form_state['values'][$field][0]['value'] = $form[$field][0]['#default_value']['value'];

    $form[$field2][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';  
    $form_state['values'][$field2][0]['value'] = $form[$field2][0]['#default_value']['value'];
    .
    .
    .

    return $form;                                                               
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you didn't show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @molot I have written similar kind of code to what that is there in the link provided. If you want the exact code then see the edit.